# disable .click function on an anchor in jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick, anchor, attr

This is written in an external .js with jquery...

I have two windows that slide in and out of view like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // hides gallery1 as soon as the DOM is ready  
  $('#gallery1').hide();  
  // shows the menu on click   
  $('#showgal1').click(function() {  
    $('#gallery1').delay(490).show('slide', {direction:'left'});
    $('#gallery2').hide('slide', {direction:'right'});
    //need code to disable showgal1 and enable showgal2
  });
  $('#showgal2').click(function() {  
    $('#gallery2').delay(490).show('slide', {direction:'right'});
    $('#gallery1').hide('slide', {direction:'left'});
    //need code to disable showgal2 and enable showgal1
  });
});
```

'gallery1' and 'gallery2' are DIV's with flash image galleries and 'showgal1' and 'showgal2' are id's of anchors...

looks like

```
<a href="#" id="showgal1">gallery 1</a>
```

I cannot find a way to disable the .click function when one is clicked and re-enable the other...

i want to disable 'showgal1' by default and when 'showgal2' event takes place it removes the attribute and makes 'showgal2' disabled until 'showgal1' is clicked...

the `.attr('disabled','disabled')` hasn't worked yet...

Comment: The correct syntax is `.attr('disabled',true)`, but it only makes sense for form elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to stop any action when a `showgal` is clicked if the associated gallery is already visible?

```
$('#showgal1').click(function(){
    if($('#gallery1').is(":visible"))
       return false;

    $('#gallery1').delay(490).show('slide', {direction:'right'});
    $('#gallery2').hide('slide', {direction:'left'});

});

$('#showgal2').click(function(){
    if($('#gallery2').is(":visible"))
       return false;
    $('#gallery2').delay(490).show('slide', {direction:'right'});
    $('#gallery1').hide('slide', {direction:'left'});

});
```

The first 2 lines of each `click` function will stop the function if the respective gallery is already visible.

Comment: both galleries are loaded with the page... in a sense they already ARE visable, the user just cant see them...   but ill try this, it looks like the simplest solution

Comment: oh wait... i understand now, but i would have to set an .attr of the DIV i am showing as 'not visible' or something, right?

Comment: works!  thanks a million, i did some digging on the 'visible' string or tag or w/e... i got a solution and learned something new! thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. ':visible' is one of the neatest jQuery `selectors` - http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.attr('onclick','void(0)');
```

Comment: Please no.  Setting an `onclick` attribute using jQuery is backwards and bound to be a bad way of doing whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: setting the onclick attribute is an old way of binding event handlers and it's avoided whenever possible. One of the reasons is that it supports only one handler to be bound at a time. jQuery provides a complete framework for event handling that offers far more functionality, including the ability to bind multiple handlers, unbind all of them or just some of them, bind them so they automatically remove themselves after being triggered once, use namespaces, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the info Box9. I thought that OP's intent was to disable the onclick event for the element completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class "disabled" to the link when it is clicked. Note that this won't disable the links by itself, nor will setting the disabled attribute as you've tried, as only form elements such as inputs and buttons can be disabled. But you can check inside your click handlers whether the class is there, and if it is, do nothing:

```
$("#showgal1").hide();
$("#showgal2").addClass("disabled");

// shows the menu on click   
$('#showgal1').click(function() {  
   if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) return false;

   // Note the extra .addClass or .removeClass on the end
   $('#gallery1').delay(490).show('slide', {direction:'left'}).addClass("disabled");
   $('#gallery2').hide('slide', {direction:'right'}).removeClass("disabled");
});
$('#showgal2').click(function() {  
   if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) return false

   $('#gallery2').delay(490).show('slide', {direction:'right'}).addClass("disabled");
   $('#gallery1').hide('slide', {direction:'left'}).removeClass("disabled");
});
```

The advantage of adding a class is that you can then use CSS to give it the appearance of a disabled button:

```
.disabled {
   color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just keep a variable in your code that keeps track of which is visible by `div` name.  This will make it much easier to expand in the future if you need more panels.  Just store the name of the currently visible on in the variable and make sure the clicked item is *not* that before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but I think you want to prevent the link from triggering the click handler if the gallery is already shown.

I would use jQuery's data function to store the gallery's active state as true/false:

```
$('#showgal1').click(function() {
    var $gal1 = $(this), $gal2 = $('#gallery2');
    if(!$('#gallery1').data('active')){
        $gal1.delay(490).show('slide', {direction:'left'}).data('active', true);
        $gal2.hide('slide', {direction:'right'}).data('active', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes... thats correct i dont want them to call a gallery into view when it is already showing...  it makes the DIV's spaz out and looks very unprofessional
ill try this, but will it make the 'click' inactive or just the DIV?

Comment: this works, although it will still reload gallery1 as it is set by default to show... @Omar's solution using 'visible' worked better, but yours would work if they both started hidden

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. data() is really useful for things like this, but not so much when a selector already exists for it. Cheers.